# Clifford algebra Cliff(0) as reals, Cliff(1) as complex...

Tags: clifford-algebras

In this paper by John Baez: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node6.html he says that assuming a Clifford algebra with $vw + wv = -2<v, w>$, you can see that Cliff(0) = $\mathbb{R}$, Cliff(1) = $\mathbb{C}$ and Cliff(2) = $\mathbb{H}$...

How is that possible? The minus sign would spoil everything... Thanks in advance.

Comment: The minus sign means that $i^2 = -1$ in $\operatorname{Cliff}(1)$ and that $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$ in $\operatorname{Cliff}(2)$, which is presumably what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain how you recover Cliff(0). And for Cliff(1) you have $v, w \in \mathbb{R}$, so I can't see how the $i$ appears... Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: The Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cliff}(V)$ of an inner product space $V$ is the *unital* algebra generated by elements of $V$, subject to the relation $vw + wv = -2\langle v,w\rangle 1_{\operatorname{Cliff}(V)}$; in particular, it is generated as an algebra by the algebra's unit element $1_{\operatorname{Cliff}(V)}$ *together with* by any basis for $V$. So, this vacuously gives you $\operatorname{Cliff}(0) = \mathbb{R}$, while $\operatorname{Cliff}(1)$ is generated by the unit $1_{\operatorname{Cliff}(1)}$ *together with* the basis $\{i\}$ for the $1$-dim'l inner product space $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ok, sure I'm missing something, but let's put values: we are in $\mathbb{R}$, and for instance $v = 2, w = 3$, and the unit and basis for $\mathbb{R}$ is 1. Then the equality $vw + wv = -2\langle v, w\rangle$ is not verified...

Answer (score 1):

Let $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{K}$. First, recall that the tensor algebra generated by $V$ is the vector space
$$T(V)=\mathbb{K}\oplus V\oplus(V\otimes V)\oplus(V\otimes V\otimes V)\oplus\dots$$
In the text, Baez defines the Clifford algebra as an associative algebra generated by $V$ *modulo* the relations
$$vv=-\|v\|,$$
or equivalently
$$vw+wv=-2\langle v,w\rangle.$$
When he says "generated by $V$ modulo", it means that the product given by juxtaposition of elements $v,w\in V$ in the equations is *defined* as a product satisfying those equations. More precisely, since the product must be bilinear, the Clifford algebra will be the quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$ by an equivalence relation that will make those relations true.

Aiming to be concise, let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$. Now, if we set $n=0$, we would have $V=\{0\}$. Notice that since the juxtaposition product is bilinear, the equations above are automatically satisfied. Therefore, the Clifford algebra will be exactly the tensor algebra. However, $T(V)=\mathbb{K}\oplus\{0\}\oplus(\{0\}\otimes\{0\})\oplus\dots=\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$. It yields
$$\text{Cliff}(0)=\mathbb{R}.$$

Remark: the symbols $v$ and $w$ in the equations are elements of $V$, not from $\mathbb{K}$. Therefore, the example given in the comments of the question does not provide a counter-example.